# Syntax error on line 23 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/modsecurity.conf

Tags: amazon-ec2, mod-security

I'm try install and configure Mod_Security on Amazon EC2 Linux 64 bits, but one error happens

Syntax error on line 23 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/modsecurity.conf:
ModSecurity: Found another rule with the same id

Need help to solve this, I tried to find in many search engines, but found nothing.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Well, what's line 23 of that file, and have you checked for another line with the same ID?

Comment: [link](http://s14.postimg.org/5hg8an5k1/Captura_de_Tela_2015_08_31_s_19_14_58.png) Print of screen with error. Do you have any idea about what can solve?

Comment: Somewhere in one of your config files there's another rule with ID `200000`, or you've double-included that `.conf` file.

Comment: I removed the lines
<IfModule security2_module>
     Include conf.d / modsecurity.conf
</ IfModule>
and Apache returned to work.
My new question is: the Include conf.d/*.conf get all .conf files, thus the Include conf.d/modsecurity.conf is included by default?

Comment: Yes, `Include conf.d/*.conf` would include it, so you're double-including it, thus the error.

Comment: I followed this tutorial ( http://tutorial.centos.com.my/?p=69 ) and got success to install mod_security and mod_evasive. But php does not run, displays the code in the browser. Insert an index.php file in EC2 disk with the php code "<? Php phpinfo ();" but this is ignored and the EC2 displays the "Amazon Linux AMI Test Page" page. I did several tests but nothing works. Does anyone know a way to run php?

Answer (score 1):

You need to see if modsecurity is loaded twice or not. Go to your configuration file `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` and find "modsec". If you see two then comment one, restart apache.

For question number two:

```
<? Php phpinfo ();
```

is this the correct one?

try

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```